# CLI Being Used in Production Environment How to Secure Secrets

Tags: security, command-line-interface

I have a command line interface that I've been using now personally for about a year, recently its been going into some production servers and I've ran into an issue and as its security related and at least a little unique I figure I'd check here.

Like any CLI its dumb on start other than the context you give it, through env variables or parameters. I use an environmental variable called something like CONNECTION_PATH which points at a JSON file stored locally on the machine that has a connection string, and some other configuration parameters for connecting a database the CLI uses. This CONNECTION_PATH can vary on each call for up to 4 different connections. (e.g. 4 files) This CLI will be called/terminate intermittently and WILL not be keeping its connection context.

The server itself is going through some secret store maybe S3, irregardless, it would not be prudent for them to use the secure key store than immediately write some of its contents to disk in plain text.

I see two options here for keeping secrets secure:

- Allow that JSON connection file to be passed as raw json string in the CLI (I avoided this due to JSON being so difficult to work in the terminal but if a program is calling its more manageable) that way all the secrets are in the servers memory still
- Generate and Encrypt each of the 4 JSON files on server startup and write to disk and pass my CLI program an encryption key to decode the JSON data.

Am I missing any other security implications? Do you have another other recommendations for how to deal with this problem? Sorry I know this is more advice and less like a concrete problem.

Honestly I thought about the security implications and just wanted to hear from someone else.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using vaults , vaults are typically secure storage which allow you the flexibility of storing and encrypting data without the requirement to handle the decryption key.

Vaults provides you path which you access like URL and the corresponding resource is secured by credentials.

So in this case as you mention the use of ENV variable for storing the path , instead in the context of the CLI you keep you vault password in the ENV variable and use it in your script to access the paths of the vault where your sensitive data resides .

A number of free , paid and open source vault solutions are available you can evaluate them as per your use case.